# debounce input on amp-autocomplete

Tags: amp-html

Is there a way to debounce the requests to the server when using amp-autocomplete?

I try:

```
<form id="form1" class="formclass"
  method="get"
  action="#"
  action-xhr="/yabla_media.json/" 
  target="_top">
  <amp-autocomplete filter="none"
    query="q" 
    min-characters="2"
    src="/yabla_media.json/"
    [src]="srcUrl" 
    >
    <input on="input-debounced: AMP.setState({debounced:event.value}),form1.submit" id="input1" name="q" type="text" placeholder="search by title,description,etc..." />
</amp-autocomplete>
```

But if I look at the network tab it appears to send the requests via auto-autocomplete faster than after a 300 ms pause.

But it does seem to send yet another duplicate request after the 300 ms pause.

My question is can amp-autocomplete requests be debounced or throttled?

For a test case see https://nyc.tidalforce.org/yablamediasearch

Comment: Methinks you're gonna need to wrap this in `<amp-script>`.  the good news is that sample `debounce routines` conform to the `amp-script` rules (size, runtime duration). For example, this example may work with `amp-script`: https://medium.com/@jamischarles/what-is-debouncing-2505c0648ff1